# Use of frame layout to render multiple views

Tags: android, android-layout

I typically organize my code/logic by a fragment represent one layout. Now I am in need of few relatively simple forms to get input data from user, which are somewhat related in purpose.

Say I hav 3 screens, and I could create 3 fragments to handle them (display view, read input, submit, ..). Or should I use one fragment, and use FrameLayout create a stack of layouts. I was thinking like, stacking all 3 views and hide/display the view I like. But the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) say

> Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view,
>   because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's
>   scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping
>   each other

Any good way to do this or should I create multiple fragments for this (the down side of this is lot of small classes and repeated code. I may use a base class, still like to explore other options)

Thanks.

Comment: As long as only one childview is visible at a time, you should have no overlapping issue.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't really care that much if the views overlap each other in the `FrameLayout`, or in fact they are **supposed** to overlap because you expect to be showing only one at a time.  `FrameLayout` can certainly display stacked child views that each take up its full width and height just fine, and if you set the visibility of the unused views to `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`, they will not intercept screen presses or take focus if they happen to be located above the visible view the user is interacting with.

On the point of readability and code maintenance, I think swapping fragments makes more sense though, even if there is more memory overhead.  The layout management can be encapsulated within the individual fragments, and you do not need to worry about showing/hiding views, as fragment transactions will take care of that aspect.